# Uploading site to Plesk 12

Tags: plesk

I've never used Parallels' Plesk before and I'm trying to get my site up and running. I was using MAMP as a local server and everything worked fine, but now getting in on Plesk doesn't seem to be working.

I've connected a domain name (toptasty.gr) to the server, I've set "toptasty.gr/" as the document root (it doesn't seem to allow a default root), and inside that directory I have all my files, including an index.php.

But when I try to see my site, Chrome tells me the DNS can't find the site. I'm out of ideas, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Plesk creates a root called /httpdocs where you need to place your web files. With regards to DNS issue I would say that you have setup DNS in Plesk only. You will need to add or edit your DNS details to your hosting providers DNS or if your Domain registrar allows DNS you will need to add detail there. i.e www points to your Plesk server IP. N.B. Even though you have DNS in Plesk it is not controlling your domains DNS.